# Kobuki - Auto Docking - Action server is not connected yet

Tags: ros, action-server, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

A couple of questions - I've just got a Kobuki bot and managed to get most of the Kobuki stack complied on Pi 3 - both talking to one another now - Huzzar! :)

Wanted to try out the auto dock but is complains that it's waiting for the "Action server is not connected yet".

Is this something I need to write specifically or should I be using move_base or something else I've missed?

On a related note - given a use case that the robot is navigating to some location on a map and the battery drops below safe limits then it needs to return to base does this become a case of writing an action client to check for and deal with this situation (i.e. send goal commands http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals to find - on the map - then dock with the docking station?)

**EDIT 1**:

This is what the mobile_base_nodelet dies with:

```
process[diagnostic_aggregator-4]: started with pid [13370] nodelet: /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:109: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double; int Size = 4; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(internal::UIntPtr(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & (15)) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
 [mobile_base_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 13368, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/pi/.ros/log/1879dcbe-eae1-11e6-9b24-b827ebd5620d/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-2.log]. log file: /home/pi/.ros/log/1879dcbe-eae1-11e6-9b24-b827ebd5620d/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-2*.log
```

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253680/kobuki---auto-docking---action-server-is-not-connected-yet/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you need to first setup the action server with:

```
roslaunch kobuki_auto_docking minimal.launch
```

Then you can activate auto docking with:

```
roslaunch kobuki_auto_docking activate.launch
```

There is more info on the [auto docking tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Testing%20Automatic%20Docking), but it sounds like you just missed step one.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-03**:
Hi thanks for the reply- I've been trying that. For some reason the mobile_base_nodelet_manager- just dies. No apparent reason that I can see and nothing in the logs.

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2017-02-03**:
Does your error match [this issue](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/354)? Also, just in case, would you happen to be doing `compact.launch` instead of `minimal.launch` when the kobuki has already been launched? Because `compact.launch` would be trying to start another nodelet manager.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-04**:
Looking at that issue it does look the same. I've made the changes mentioned there but as soon as I bring up the last service (roslaunch kobuki_auto_docking activate.launch --screen) then the mobile_base_nodelet_manager just dies. Either with the error in **EDIT 1** or the one mentioned in that issu